# Unable to upload java jar in lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

Unable to upload jar file in aws lambda function it says **The deployment package of your Lambda function "helloAlexa" is too large to enable inline code editing. However, you can still invoke your function.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the deployment itself.

The only thing you are unable to do is edit the code online via AWS's console. You will have to use your own IDE/Text editor to do so.